# Abstract classes and constructor

Tags: c++, abstract-class

we are trying to implmenent a solution with abstract superclass in C++:
Control is the super class of Spline and others.
Now when we try to instantiate an object of type Spline the instantiation fails with two errors:

> 1. cannot find method with matching parameters for the constructor of class Spline
> 2. cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Control'

How can we fix those issues?

Instantiate Spline of type Control and use it in main:

```
RampFunction timeRampFn{0, 100, 2000, 1000};
RampFunction distanceRampFn{0, 0, 0.5f, 1000};

Control ctrl = new Spline(slowDownCoeff, timeRampFn, distanceRampFn);

ctrl.calculateAction(&newRobotState, p_0, p_t, targetTrack, timeFromStart, distanceToTarget);
```

Control.hpp (abstract super class):

```
#ifndef CONTROL_HPP
#define CONTROL_HPP

#include <vector>
#include <Data/Track.h>
#include <Data/TrackPoint.h>
#include <Data/RobotState.h>
#include <boost/multiprecision/eigen.hpp>

using Eigen::Vector2f;
using namespace std;

class Control
{
private:
const float FUTURE_INTERVAL = 0.1f;

protected:
const int FUTURE_SIZE = 10;

public:
virtual void calculateAction(RobotState *state, Vector2f curPos, Vector2f refPos, Track targetTrack, float timeFromStart, float distanceToTarget) = 0;
};

#endif
```

Spline.hpp:

```
#ifndef SPLINE_HPP
#define SPLINE_HPP

#include <Control/Control.hpp>

using Eigen::Vector2f;
using namespace std;

class Spline : Control
{
private:
struct RampFunction
{
    float x_0, val_0;
    float x_e, val_e;
};
float slowDownCoeff;
RampFunction timeRampFn;
RampFunction distanceRampFn;

public:
Spline(float slowDownCoeff, RampFunction timeRampFn, RampFunction distanceRampFn)
{
    this->slowDownCoeff = slowDownCoeff;
    this->timeRampFn = timeRampFn;
    this->distanceRampFn = distanceRampFn;
}
virtual void calculateAction(RobotState *state, Vector2f curPos, Vector2f refPos, Track targetTrack, float timeFromStart, float distanceToTarget);
};

#endif
```

Comment: You can want `Control *ctrl = new …`

Comment: You also need to implement `calculateAction()` in your spline class.

Comment: `Control ctrl = new Spline(slowDownCoeff, timeRampFn, distanceRampFn);` - that makes no sense at all. `ctrl` is a concrete object (or about to be); not a pointer, and has no conversion constructor (which would be silly and an obvious design smell anyway). The followup code `ctrl.calculateAction` suggests you *think* this is a proper method for accessing polymorphic behavior; it isn't. Instead, `std::unique_ptr<Control> ctrl = std::make_unique<Spline>(...args...);`, then `ctrl->calculateAction(...);` seems like what you *probably* want.

Comment: Thanks WhozCraig for your suggestion. Sadly it didnt work perfectly. I have changed it to `std::unique_ptr<Control> ctrl(new Spline(...));`. That works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> Control ctrl = ...
> ```

You have created a variable of type `Control`. This is not allowed because `Control` is an abstract type. This is why you get the error `cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Control'`.

Another problem would be that `Control` doesn't have a constructor that would take an argument of type `Spline*`.

---

What you may have been trying to do is to create a base pointer to the derived object: `Control* ctrl = ...`. However, this would make deleting the dynamic allocation problematic, since you aren't allowed to delete through the base pointer because the destructor of the base is non-virtual. A solution is to declare the destructor virtual.

But simply making deletion allowed is not sufficient. You should actually perform the deletion or else the memory may leak.

Answer (score 2):

This should be the modified code you would want.

main.cpp

```
RampFunction timeRampFn{0, 100, 2000, 1000};
RampFunction distanceRampFn{0, 0, 0.5f, 1000};

Control *ctrl = new Spline(slowDownCoeff, timeRampFn, distanceRampFn);

ctrl->calculateAction(&newRobotState, p_0, p_t, targetTrack, timeFromStart, 
distanceToTarget);
```

Control.hpp

```
#ifndef CONTROL_HPP
#define CONTROL_HPP

#include <vector>
#include <Data/Track.h>
#include <Data/TrackPoint.h>
#include <Data/RobotState.h>
#include <boost/multiprecision/eigen.hpp>

using Eigen::Vector2f;
using namespace std;

class Control
{
private:
const float FUTURE_INTERVAL = 0.1f;

protected:
const int FUTURE_SIZE = 10;

public:
virtual ~Control() {}
virtual void calculateAction(RobotState *state, Vector2f curPos, Vector2f refPos, Track targetTrack, float timeFromStart, float distanceToTarget) = 0;
};

#endif
```

Spline.hpp

```
#ifndef SPLINE_HPP
#define SPLINE_HPP

#include <Control/Control.hpp>

using Eigen::Vector2f;
using namespace std;

class Spline : Control
{
private:
struct RampFunction
{
    float x_0, val_0;
    float x_e, val_e;
};
float slowDownCoeff;
RampFunction timeRampFn;
RampFunction distanceRampFn;

public:
Spline(float slowDownCoeff, RampFunction timeRampFn, RampFunction distanceRampFn)
: slowDownCoeff(slowDownCoeff), timeRampFn(timeRampFn), distanceRampFn(distanceRampFn) {}

virtual void calculateAction(RobotState *state, Vector2f curPos, Vector2f refPos, Track targetTrack, float timeFromStart, float distanceToTarget);
};

#endif
```